# Remove decimals after a numeric value in java

Tags: java, excel, decimal

Hi I have a excel file reading application which reads every cell in the file.

whenever a cell contains a numeric value the app is treating it a numeric cell.

For example the cell contains (40002547) the application will treat this as numeric cell. I cab get the value by using this code:

```
SONum = String.valueOf(cellSONum.getNumericCellValue());
```

Well that works fine. My Problem is it appends decimal at the end of the string. it will be (40002547.0). I need it to be as is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `cellSONum.getNumericCellValue()` is returning a floating point type. If you force it to an integer *before* calling `valueOf()`, you should get the string representation in an integral form, if indeed that's what you want for *all* possibilities:

```
SONum = String.valueOf((int)cellSONum.getNumericCellValue());
```

You can see this in the following code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        double d = 1234;
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(d));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf((int)d));
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
1234.0
1234
```

---

However, if you want to just get rid of `.0` at the end of any string but allow non-integral values to survive, you can just remove the trailing text yourself:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        double d1 = 1234;
        double d2 = 1234.567;
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(d1).replaceFirst("\\.0+$", ""));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(d2).replaceFirst("\\.0+$", ""));
    }
}
```

That snippet outputs:

```
1234
1234.567
```

Comment: appending the (int) got it working! thanks! up vote please! hahhaha

Answer (score 2):

Try with `split()`.

```
         SONum = String.valueOf(cellSONum.getNumericCellValue());
         SONum  = SONum.split("\\.")[0];
```

When you split  `40002547.0`  with `.` ,the split function returns two parts and the first one you need.

Comment: that returns an error Sir. but I already got it working, Thanks any way

Comment: "Cannot invoke split(String) on the primitive type double"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure you are not cutting of any valid decimals, you can use regexp also:

```
String pattern = "\.0+"; // dot followed by any number of zeros
System.out.println(String.valueOf(cellSONum.getNumericCellValue()).replaceAll(pattern, ""));
```

More on java regexp for example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Double \ inside strings, you have to escape the escape :-)

Answer (score 2):

As PaxDiablo also mentions, cellSONum.getNumericCellValue() returns a floating point.

You can cast this to Long or int to get rid of all behind the '.'

```
String SONum = String.valueOf(cellSONum.getNumericCellValue().longValue());
```

used as example:

```
String SONum = String.valueOf((new Double(0.5)).longValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SONum = ""+cellSONum.getNumericCellValue().split(".")[0];
```

Comment: It returns an error "Cannot invoke split(String) on the primitive type double"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
double value = 23.0;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.println("bd value::"+ df.format(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).
You could simply say

```
BigDecimal scaledDecimal = new BigDecimal(value).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help in case your input is String and you need result also in String

1). Convert the string to Double using Double.parseDouble,

2). Type cast to int, then convert to string using String.valueOf()

```
private String formatText(String text) {
    try {
        return String.valueOf((int) Double.parseDouble(text));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do Explicit type casting to remove the decimals,

```
double desvalue = 3.586;
int value = (int)desvalue;
```